# Как выделить "вот-вот" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Знатоки русского языка! Имеется вот такая фраза:

*Мики тоже улыбается, но в животе вспыхивает страх — глупо, но кажется, вот-вот и чужие пальцы нащупают горло.*

Что-то я запуталась в знаках препинания вокруг "вот-вот" и прошу вашей помощи.

глупо, но кажется — вот-вот, и чужие пальцы нащупают горло?
глупо, но кажется: вот-вот — и чужие пальцы нащупают горло?

Или еще как-то? И почему?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Вот-вот***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_97) в этом предложении является наречием. В предложениях со "спокойной" интонацией не требует обособления.

*Вот-вот и сама она должна была наконец приехать на каникулы домой.* [Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя] (Национальный корпус русского языка).

В Вашем предложении другая ситуация, и Вы правы: после ***вот-вот*** очень просится знак препинания. На мой взгляд, это должно быть тире, как более "эмоциональный" знак. После ***кажется*** я бы оставил запятую (по принципу *...кажется, что...*). Но тогда ***глупо, но кажется, вот-вот*** будет находиться между двух тире и выглядеть как вставка.

В НКРЯ нашёлся похожий пример:

*Когда на нее это находит, она становится похожа на впадающего в транс шамана: кажется, вот-вот — и она отбросит свою палитру, размажет косметику по лицу, взлохматит волосы и примется с завыванием скакать по квартире.* [Сергей Иванов. Марш авиаторов // «Звезда», 2002].

Думаю, что предложение можно оформить по такой же схеме:

*Мики тоже улыбается, но в животе вспыхивает страх: глупо, но кажется, вот-вот — и чужие пальцы нащупают горло.*

Answer (score 2):

**Лирическое отступление для хорошего настроения** (из книги Н. Абгарян "Манюня")

Два горных орла кружили в небе.

— *Видишь хоть кого живо-о-о-го-о-о?* — кричал орёл с этого конца горизонта.

— *Не-е-е-ет!* — отзывался второй с другого конца.

Этому ответу очень не хватает альтернативных решений, так что очень хочется добавить **хотя бы еще один вариант**:

*Мики тоже улыбается, но в животе вспыхивает страх: **глупо, но кажется, что вот-вот — и чужие пальцы нащупают горло.***

Пояснение

1) ***Вот-вот***  — это действительно наречие, а тире перед союзом И обозначает резкий или неожиданный переход, сравнить: ...*еще мгновение — и чужие пальцы нащупают горло.*

2) Несколько тире в предложении использовать нежелательно, так как они могут восприниматься как парный знак, поэтому ставим **двоеточие.**

3)  Используем союзную связь (**союз ЧТО**). *Кажется* — это сказуемое (не вводное слово), а бессоюзной связью и только запятой в  предложении такой структуры (с тире)  не обойтись.

4) **Проверяем интонацию**. Вроде бы всё нормально: увеличенная пояснительная пауза, обозначенная двоеточием, а далее три фразы, разделенные паузами (паузы перед ЧТО нет). Вполне себе выразительно.

*Мики тоже улыбается, но в животе вспыхивает страх: глУпо, // но кажется, что вот-вОт // — и чужие пальцы нащупают гОрло.*

Comment: Sharon  Извините, мне кажется, что альтернативным решением вопроса была бы иная расстановка знаков. Вы же только изменили предложение, добавив _что_ , что, безусловно, читается лучше, но ничего по сути не меняет. Да, спасибо за анекдот!

Comment: А разве союз ЧТО не альтернативное решение? Он даже  намного важнее, чем иная расстановка знаков.  Без этого союза ваша запятая после «кажется» попросту НЕВЕРНА, или я ошибаюсь? При бессоюзной связи с изъяснительным значением надо ставить двоеточие или тире, а их там и так хватает. Мне пришлось подумать над решением этой задачи, и без этого союза ничего не получалось. И тогда у меня к вам вопрос: как вы объясняете постановку этой запятой? Как здесь выбрать корректную грамматику и правильно ее обозначить?

Comment: Получается, в примере из НКРЯ, который я привел, тоже ошибка? (И в моем этом предложении "Получается, (что)..." тоже без _что_ нельзя?) Если следовать правилам, то запятая ставится только в перечислительных БСП. Но вы ведь сами часто (по моим ощущениям, насколько я успел заметить за три месяца) говорите, что нельзя формально относиться к правилам, с чем я полностью согласен. В своем ответе я указал, что запятая ставится так же, как и в сочетании _кажется, что_... Я объясняю эту запятую просто пропуском этого союза. Неужели это так НЕВЕРНО?

Comment: А вот знаки в БСП надо ставить по своим правилам. В заданном предложении сочетание «но кажется» не получается сделать вводным, это именно сказуемое перед изъяснительной частью, и тогда нужно тире или двоеточие. Если же мы переходим от БСП к СПП, то ничего не нужно, даже интонация сохраняется именно та, что лучше всего подходит. Всё четко, все по правилам, ни один редактор не придерется. Поэтому мы не можем говорить, что это СПП, где мы пропустили союз: если нет союза – значит, это БСП и запятую ставить нельзя.

Comment: Про вводное речи не идет. Ну да ладно, пусть будет по правилам.

Comment: А что вы можете сказать на мой вопрос о Марфе-царевне? Мне не дает покоя пример про Борьку в Розентале:)

Comment: Забыл тогда плюс поставить!